# Merging uploaded file chunks in php result in corrupt files

Tags: javascript, php, file-upload, corrupt

I am developing a file uploader section in my app. The client side is Vue.js and the backend is PHP. Using Laravel as my framework.

I am slicing up the selected files at the client side using Blob.slice() (I have also tried FileReader Api, Resumablejs, Now working on my own implementation). Data is sent using xhr (tried Axios, XMLHTTPRequest), one request per "slice" or "chunk". I fetch the data at the backend and save the incoming file as "chunk1", "chunk2" ... and so on. Upon receiving the last chunk, I merge the chunks using PHP.

My problem is that the merged file somehow corrupts. mp4s - not playable or not seekable, exes - corrupt, some exes do good but not all (its unpredictable), some small pdfs survive.

Failed Attempts

1. Send sliced data with multipart/form-data

--- save chunk with Storage::put() or Storage::putFileAs()
--- save chunk with fopen(file, 'wb' or 'ab'), fwrite(), fclose()
--- save chunk with file_put_contents

2. Send sliced data with base64 encoding

--- save chunk as received (base64 encoded) -> read each chunk with base64_decode() while saving data in new file
--- append all chunks as received (base64 encoded) to one file -> later create a new file decoding this appended file. (this attempt was by far the most successful one but still some files corrupted, especially exes).

Client side code ...

```
upload(file, start = 0, request = 0) {
        let chunkSize = 1024 * 1024 * 3;
        let end = (start + chunkSize) > file.fileObject.size ? file.fileObject.size : (start + chunkSize);
        let reader = new FileReader();
        let slice = file.fileObject.slice(start, end);

        reader.onload = (e) => {

            let data = {
                fileName: file.fileObject.name,
                chunkNumber: request + 1,
                totalChunks: Math.ceil(file.fileObject.size / chunkSize),
                chunk: reader.result.split(',')[1]
            }

            axios({
                url: '/api/admin/batch-sessions/'+ this.batchSessionId +'/files',
                method: 'POST',
                data: data,
                headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
            })
            .then(res => {
                start += chunkSize;
                request++;

                if (start <= file.fileObject.size) {
                    this.upload(file, start, request);
                }
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log(err.message);
            });
        }

        reader.readAsDataURL(slice);
    }
```

Server side code ...

```
public function handle()
{
    $chunks = Storage::disk('s3-upload-queue')
        ->files($this->directory);

    $mergedFile = Storage::disk('s3-upload-queue')->path($this->directory.'/'.basename($this->directory));
    $base64File = Storage::disk('s3-upload-queue')->path($this->directory.'/'.basename($this->directory).'.b64');

    $mfs = fopen($mergedFile, 'wb');
    $b64fs = fopen($base64File, 'r');

    fwrite($mfs, base64_decode(fread($b64fs, filesize($base64File))));

    fclose($mfs);
    fclose($b64fs);
}
```

Actually I do not have in-depth knowledge about different encodings, was reading about base64 chunking here on stackoverflow and tried to create "slice" of size (1024 * 1024 * 3). this is when most files were merged successfully using base64 encoded transfer. but that too was unpredictable. some files still corrupted. I am trying to understand this properly.
Please let me know if more info is needed. Thanks.

Comment: Why do you even slice & upload? why not upload the hole file at once? And why do you use eg axios instead of say the [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API)? base64 and json is not a good container for uploading data, it's wasteful... a better suited format is application/multipart using [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData)

Comment: I need to slice and upload because the file sizes vary from 50mb to 1gb. So uploading whole file at once is not an option. I have tried fetch too. Also tried multipart with FormData. Turned to base64 as an alternative. I dont think the problem is at the client side, Its something I am messing up when I merge those "chunks" on the server side.

Comment: @KJ But even if I send my chunks as regular FormData the merged file is corrupt. When I read the documentation for libraries such as ResumableJs, Uppy, Plupload (all support sliced /chunked upload) talk about simply merging back the chunks on the server. I am really confused.

Answer (score 0):

```
chunk: reader.result.split(',')[1]
```

What is it? Are you removing base64 prefix? It does not exists in chunks, so your chunk is always empty as there is nothing on index "1", as string is not splitted.

I would also use such code to get blob:

```
let blob = file.slice(offset, length + offset);
file.fileReader.readAsBinaryString(blob);



file.fileReader.onload = async function() {
     let base64 = btoa(this.result)
   // Do whatever you want
}
```

About corruptions, also wonder how do you know if all chunks were send successfully? Do you keap log of chunks on server side, not only on client side?